# Clean and readable way for settings variables in Makefile targets

Tags: makefile

Here is how I am currently customizing my Makefile variables for different targets (toy example):

```
#set default values
ARG_A = 100
ARG_B = 50
OP    = ,

#combine vars for easier reuse in multiple targets
OPTS = $(ARG_A) $(OP) $(ARG_B)

math:
    python -c "print $(OPTS)"

#add custom targets with various variable overrides
plus: OP=+
plus: math

minus: OP=-
minus: math

plus100: ARG_B = 100
plus100: plus

minus100: ARG_B = 100
minus100: minus

custom: ARG_A = 29
custom: ARG_B = 149
custom: OP = *
custom: math
```

This already looks clean and readable to me, as it does not use any fancy if-then-else patterns and does not abuse `$(shell ...)` for the logic.

**Question**: Is there a better (but still clean) way to achieve the listed variable overrides? In particular, I like to get rid of the repeated `target:` names.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Make doesn't really have a way to combine two variable assignments into a single line, so `custom: ARG_A = 29` and `custom: ARG_B = 149` must be separate. Likewise, `custom: ARG_A = 29` and `custom: math` are doing fundamentally different things, and Make doesn't allow them to be combined. It *could*, but it doesn't. (And if it did, the result would be less readable than what you have.)